# Why do we need run update before run install in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dependencies

When I try to specify Boost library for my app in Dockerfile, I have to do

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libboost-dev
```

If I just add

```
RUN apt-get install libboost-dev
```

I got error:

```
returned a non-zero code: 100
```

What is the theory behind this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Base images are often built with `apt-get clean` at the end to remove local caches of package lists and thus reduce image sizes. When you start building upon such an image, package lists are empty and `apt-get` cannot find any packages. `apt-get update` downloads most current package lists, allowing a subsequent `apt-get install` to find, download and install packages.